# Acer Aspire One D255 touchpad movement & clicking issues

Tags: 11.10, mouse, touchpad, acer, aspire-one

After installing Ubuntu 11.10 I've got this problem. My cursor always moves to the upper right-hand corner where the power cog is every time I touch my touchpad even in 1/10 second. After that,I can move it with a mouse but cannot click everywhere, just move and move. I can only use a mouse normally when the system was restarted and I didn't touch the touchpad at all, because when I touch it, I can only move the cursor again. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I have an Acer Aspire aswell, and I found that my touchpad stopped working entirely, I fixed it by installing "Synaptics Touchpad configuration" and rebooted, everything worked again. Maybe this works for you too?!